# installing HWIOAuthBundle via composer exception about wrong php version

Tags: php, windows, symfony, hwioauthbundle

Hi I want install to project on symfony [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md)

My PHP version (in CLI): 7.1.11
Symfony version: 2.8.31

but after running command:

`composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle`

i get this exception:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Could not find package php-http/guzzle6-adapter at any version matching you
>     r PHP version 5.3.9.0

I was updated php before i had 5.3.9 but if i run command `php -v` i see right version 7.1.11 in CLI and on web (debug symfony bar) is again 7.1.11 version. Php path in enviroment variables was not change - new php is in same directory. And old php dir was renamed.

Comment: Please link your `composer.json` file, you should see a reference to PHP 5.3.9 version in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `platform` config in you `composer.json`:

`"config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.1.11"
        }
    },`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform